# Gboard settings keeps crashing

Tags: crashes, gboard

I am running Resurrection Remix, Nougat 7.1.1 on a Nexus 6p. I have Gboard "6.0.79.144029707-arm64-v8a" installed. I can open settings, but when I choose one of the settings categories, I get the message saying "Gboard has stopped", How do I fix this?

Comment: I have the same issue. The answers around the net prove thatmost  people just don't read the question: "Going to the settings crashes the app." -> "Go to settings and make sure blbalba". Come on... Then you get an advice to report the problem... By going to the settings. Well done Google, you've got a problem that will never be reported, because the reporting channel is part of the problem. Anyhoo. I'm on a OnePlus X using Lineage 14, I used OpenGApps to get GBoard. Then I tried to wipe the cache and the dalvik cache, no cigar so far. I'll be sure to help you if I find anything.

Comment: @Doodloo Same here. I am using Gapps from opengapps.org and I think that that might be the problem.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the problem by updating Gboard from scratch. I also updated my OS to LineageOS.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have made sure that Gboard is your default keyboard for your device, please check if you're able to navigate to the app's preferences by going to your device's Settings > language & input > Gboard > Preferences. Here you can choose your keyboard preferences for Gboard.

If the app still crashes, I'd suggest you report this to the product developers directly by sending a feedback. To submit feedback, go to your device's Settings > Language and input > Virtual Keyboard > Select Gboard > Tap on the menu icon on the top right corner > Send Feedback.

Comment: The OP just mentioned that the bug occurs when trying to go to the preferences, preciselly.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a Samsung J7 2016 phone, and the only solution that works is switching to the Samsung virtual keyboard. That works fine and I am not receiving any crashes with it. I also believe that I can find other "virtual keyboards" to download on Google Play Store, but have not tried it, since the Samsung one works just fine.